# Trying to reproduce "must declare a body" compiler error

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to reproduce the [C# compiler error CS0840](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397743.aspx) with the exact code that's given in the website:

```
class Test36
{
    public int myProp { get; } // CS0840

    // to create a read-only property
    // try the following line instead
    public int myProp2 { get; private set; }

}

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Test36 test = new Test36();
}
```

I'm running it on .NET 4.0 using Visual Studio Community 2015. Surprisingly, I cannot reproduce it. Compiler doesn't throw any error:

[image]

Why the compiler isn't throwing any error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using Visual Studio 2015, which implements C# 6. The fact that you're targeting .NET 4 is irrelevant - most of the C# 6 language features don't depend on framework features at all. The C# 6 code you're using can *easily* be compiled without reference to any modern CLR or framework features - it could have worked with .NET 1.0 if the language designers had decided to :)

You'll need to set you language level to C# 5 to see an error here. Do that in the project properties / Build / Advanced dialog:

[image: Advanced build properties dialog]

You'll then get this error:

> error CS8026: Feature 'readonly automatically implemented properties' is not available in C# 5.  Please use language version 6 or greater.

Admittedly that's not the error you actually wanted to see - I think you'll need to use an earlier version of the compiler to get that exact error.

Comment: Can't wait for the C# 6 spec to be released, which presumably won't call this a compiler error any more.

Comment: The project compiles fine in C# 3, 4, 5 and 6. It fails to compile on ISO-1 and ISO-2. When compiled with ISO-2, I get the following error: `CS8023 Feature 'automatically implemented properties' is not available in C# 2.  Please use language version 3 or greater.`

Comment: @Donotalo: That would only be the case for the *second* property. The first property (`public int myProp { get; }`) really won't compile in C# 5 mode. I tested it myself, hence the error message referring to "readonly automatically implemented properties".

Comment: @JonSkeet: I've removed the second property from code. The first property `public int myProp { get; }` really compiled in C# 3, 4 and 5.

Comment: @Donotalo: I'm afraid I just don't believe you - the error message you've shown doesn't tie up with it either. I suspect you're misdiagnosing it. (I'm not suggesting you're deliberately lying, of course - just that you're mistaken.)

Comment: @JonSkeet: How can I convince you? I've just rechecked that `class Test
    {
        public int myProp { get; }
    }` compiles in `C# 3` using VS 2015 Community.

Comment: @Donatolo: It really, really shouldn't - and it doesn't on my installation. Can you email me a zip file with your solution? My address is in my profile.

Comment: @Donotalo: Just as a long-shot - I've got update 1 installed. If you haven't installed that yet, perhaps it's a bug which is fixed in update 1?

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is because you are on Visual Studio 2015 with C# 6 which allows you to specify properties that are only set from the constructor (aka [read-only properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx)).

See the following example:

```
class Test
{
    public Test() // <-- this one does compile since it is the constructor
    {
        MyProp = 1;
    }

    public void SomeMethod() // <-- this one doesn't compile
    {
        MyProp = 1;
    }

    public int MyProp { get; } // <-- no CS0840 any more!
}
```

Comment: Your final property *isn't* a read-only property. It's a "read public, write private" property. Only `myprop` is a genuinely read-only property.

Comment: Agreed, but that is the official documentation's code block :) @JonSkeet

Comment: Complete with unconventional name? Could you link to that documentation?

Comment: Sure, it is in the question... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397743.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, that's very poor documentation, IMO. (Aside from anything else, I wouldn't want the documentation to use unconventional names like this.) I think your answer would be better without the taint here :)